# Opencascade.js - How to access the actual string in a TCollection_ExtendedString

Tags: javascript, typescript, emscripten, opencascade

I am trying to access the name of an assembly part that I have parsed from a .step file. I am using the same approach as shown in this blog entry: https://dev.opencascade.org/content/finding-name-assembly-part-step-file-using-xde but in javascript.
I am able to extract the TDataStd_Name attribute of the Labels, which contain a TCollection_ExtendedString object:

```
assembly.GetShapes(labels);
var freeShape = labels.First();
var components = new oc.TDF_LabelSequence_1();
oc.XCAFDoc_ShapeTool.GetComponents(freeShape, components, true);
var compLabel = components.First();
var name = new oc.Handle_TDF_Attribute_1();
compLabel.FindAttribute_1(oc.TDataStd_Name.GetID(), name);
var TCollection_ExtendedString = name.get().Get();
// this fails:
const nameString = TCollection_ExtendedString.ToExtString();
const nameChar =TCollection_ExtendedString.Value(0);
```

When I try to access the information contained in the object by calling TCollection_ExtendedString.ToExtString() I run into a binding error: "Cannot call TCollection_ExtendedString.ToExtString due to unbound types: PKDs'"
I have also tried to access the string character by character using TCollection_ExtendedString.Value(), which also gives me a binding error.
Does anyone know a workaround for this problem ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
assembly.GetShapes(labels);
var freeShape = labels.First();
var components = new oc.TDF_LabelSequence_1();
oc.XCAFDoc_ShapeTool.GetComponents(freeShape, components, true);
var compLabel = components.First();
var name = new oc.Handle_TDF_Attribute_1();
compLabel.FindAttribute_1(oc.TDataStd_Name.GetID(), name);
var TCollection_ExtendedString = name.get().Get();

const nameString = new oc.TCollection_AsciiString_13(TCollection_ExtendedString, 0).ToCString();
```

Comment: Hello Zhan, thank you for helping. The string I get from your anwers is "=>[0:1:1:6]". I was hoping to get the Name of the assembly part which would be "Pkg_Assembly_Final". I will check my previous code for errors